# How to use Nokogiri and XPath to get nodes with multiple attributes

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to parse an HTML file with some fairly eccentric markup.  Specifically, I'm trying to grab divs which have both ids, multiple classes and styles defined.

The markup looks something like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar" class="baz bang" style="display: block;">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <dl>
      List of stuff
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to grab the `<dl>` which sits inside the problem `<div>`.  I can get divs with a single id attribute with no problem, but I can't figure out a way of getting Nokogiri to grab divs with both ids *and* classes.

So these work fine:

```
content = @doc.xpath("//div[id='foo']")
content = @doc.css('div#foo')
```

But these don't return anything:

```
content = @doc.xpath("//div[id='bar']")
content = @doc.xpath("div#bar")
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an XPath expression that select the wanted `<div>` based on a combination of values for its attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can get divs with a single id
>   attribute with no problem, but I can't
>   figure out a way of getting Nokogiri
>   to grab divs with both ids and
>   classes.

**You want**:

```
//div[id='bar' and class='baz bang' and style='display: block;']
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = %{
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar" class="baz bang" style="display: block;">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <dl>
      List of stuff
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
content = doc
  .xpath("//div[@id='foo']/div[@id='bar' and @class='baz bang']/dl")
  .inner_html

puts content
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `content = @doc.xpath("div#bar")` is a typo and should be `content = @doc.css("div#bar")` or better `content = @doc.css("#bar")`. The first expression in your second code chunk seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I'm trying to grab divs which have
>   both ids, multiple classes and styles
>   defined

And

> I'm attempting to grab the `<dl>` which sits inside the problem div

So, this XPath 1.0:

```
//div[@id][contains(normalize-space(@class),' ')][@style]/dl
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using CSS selectors as a starting point rather than XPath as CSS are more readable and less likely to result in visual noise.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar" class="baz bang" style="display: block;">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <dl>
      List of stuff
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
EOT
```

Once that's parsed, using CSS to look for `<div ... id="foo">`:

```
doc.at('div#foo').to_html 
# => "<div id=\"foo\">\n" +
#    "  <div id=\"bar\" class=\"baz bang\" style=\"display: block;\">\n" +
#    "    <h2>title</h2>\n" +
#    "    <dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>\n" +
#    "  </div>\n" +
#    "</div>"
```

And `<div id="bar">`:

```
doc.at('div#bar').to_html 
# => "<div id=\"bar\" class=\"baz bang\" style=\"display: block;\">\n" +
#    "    <h2>title</h2>\n" +
#    "    <dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>\n" +
#    "  </div>"
```

We can search for tags with both class names:

```
doc.at('.baz.bang').to_html
# => "<div id=\"bar\" class=\"baz bang\" style=\"display: block;\">\n" +
#    "    <h2>title</h2>\n" +
#    "    <dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>\n" +
#    "  </div>"
```

And we can look for the explicit div with both classes and its embedded `<dl>` tag:

```
doc.at('div.baz.bang dl').to_html
# => "<dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>"
```

Or even by ID and classes:

```
doc.at('div#bar.baz.bang').to_html
# => "<div id=\"bar\" class=\"baz bang\" style=\"display: block;\">\n" +
#    "    <h2>title</h2>\n" +
#    "    <dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>\n" +
#    "  </div>"
```

And with the `<dl>`:

```
doc.at('div#bar.baz.bang dl').to_html
# => "<dl>\n" +
#    "      List of stuff\n" +
#    "    </dl>"
```

I'm using `at` which is equivalent to using `search(...some selector...).first`. Nokogiri supports `search` and `css` and `xpath`, which are its CSS and XPath variations and which return a NodeSet, and `at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` which return a Node. It's important to understand the difference between "[`NodeSet`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html)" and  "[Node](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)" and how they relate to `text`, and  [`Searchable`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html), so read the documentation.